# Beginner SQL question: arithmetic with multiple COUNT(*) results

Tags: sql, statistics, count

Continuing with the spirit of using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to learn SQL, (see: [Can we become our own “Northwind” for teaching SQL / databases?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51395/can-we-become-our-own-northwind-for-teaching-sql-databases)), I've decided to try to write a query to answer a simple question (on meta): [What % of stackoverflow users have over 10,000 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51635/what-of-stackoverflow-users-have-over-10-000-rep).

Here's what I've done:

#### [Query#1](http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1663)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Users
WHERE
  Users.Reputation >= 10000
```

Result:

```
556
```

#### [Query#2](http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1660)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  USERS
```

Result:

```
227691
```

Now, how do I put them together into one query? What is this query idiom called? What do I need to write so I can get, say, a one-row three-column result like this:

```
556     227691      0,00244190592
```

Comment: OK, just found out that there are lots of dupes that I should probably read first. I wasn't quick enough to delete before Mark Byers answered, so I undeleted it for now. Feel free to close for dupes if community feels like it.

Comment: I've fixed my answer. I'd be interested to see if there is a better way to do it.  Also, can you link to the dupes, then we can decide if this should be closed or merged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
WITH c1 AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Users
    WHERE Users.Reputation >= 10000
), c2 AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Users
)
SELECT c1.cnt, c2.cnt, CAST(c1.cnt AS FLOAT) / c2.cnt
FROM c1, c2
```

Comment: Can you make this work on SEDE? Link to the query with result etc? I still get `incorrect syntax near c2` with this.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Interesting that it doesn't work. Do you know what the database is? I tested the query in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I'm still puzzled why multiple CTEs aren't working in the SEDE.

Comment: @Daniel: I hope this doesn't mean that SEDE is too "broken" for learning =(

Comment: Oops, I just messed up copying it. JOIN without ON was the problem. The CTEs work fine now that I've fixed the error.

Comment: Works fine now :) ... @polygenelubricants: Now you have three working versions to play with! ... This is the most elegant query IMO, but note that the `WITH` clause is not directly supported in some databases such as MySQL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from [using CTEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934192/beginner-sql-question-arithmetic-with-multiple-count-results/2934207#2934207), in this case you could also have done:

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Users.Reputation >= 10000) AS float)  /
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS) * 100  AS Percentage​
```

The cast as float was to force a floating-point division, because with integer division 556 / 227691 would give 0.

Comment: It was awesome to see you work on SEDE's recent queries within the past 10 minutes =)

Comment: @polygenelubricants: lol, I wasn't aware that queries were viewable in the recent tab :) ... Good to know!

Comment: +1 for remembering cast! He probably wants all three values on a single row though.

Comment: @Mark: True. That wouldn't look nice with my approach!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the other answers here, I've written the following queries, all of which work on SEDE:

#### "Inline view"

```
SELECT *, CAST([10K] AS FLOAT)/[All] AS [Ratio]
FROM (
   SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users) AS [All],
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users Where Reputation >= 10000) AS [10K]
) AS UsersCount
```

([See query result](http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1778))

---

#### Variables

```
DECLARE @numAll FLOAT
DECLARE @num10kers FLOAT

SET @numAll = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users)
SET @num10kers = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Users.Reputation >= 10000);

SELECT  @num10kers AS [10K], @numAll AS [All], @num10Kers/@numAll AS [Ratio]
```

([See query result](http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1762))

#### References

- [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual/User variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

---

#### Common Table Expression

```
WITH Users10K AS ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM Users
    WHERE Users.Reputation >= 10000
), UsersAll AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) As Count
    FROM Users
)
SELECT
    Users10K.Count AS [10K],
    UsersAll.Count AS [All],
    CAST(Users10K.Count AS FLOAT) / UsersAll.Count AS [Ratio]
FROM Users10K, UsersAll
```

([See query result](http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1773))

#### References

- [MSDN/Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

For queries like this, where I'm doing multiple counts on a single table based on different criteria, I like to use `SUM` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    UsersCount.[10K],
    UsersCount.[All],
    (CAST(UsersCount.[10K] AS FLOAT) / UsersCount.[All]) AS [Ratio]
FROM
    (SELECT
         SUM(CASE
               WHEN Users.Reputation >= 10000 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             END) AS [10K],
         COUNT(*) AS [All]
     FROM Users) AS UsersCount
```

([query results](http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1860))

The advantage is that you're only scanning the Users table once, which may be significantly faster.

Comment: Yep, I saw this one being made in the recent queries =)

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH tmp as (
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS repCount, (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Users ) AS totalCount
FROM Users
WHERE Users.Reputation > 10000
)
SELECT tmp.repCount, tmp.totalCount, (cast(tmp.repCount as decimal(10,2))/tmp.TotalCount) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM tmp
```

UPDATED: without the with

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS repCount, (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Users ) AS totalCount, 
    (CAST((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Users WHERE Users.Reputation > 10000) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) /
        (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Users )) * 100 AS Persantage
FROM Users
```

Comment: Can you make this work on SEDE with link to query and result? I get various errors.

Comment: The decimal type was a bit too small so it was returning an overflow error. And `UserID` had to be `Id`

Answer (score 2):

Using [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) in MySQL:

```
SELECT @a:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Users.Reputation >= 10000),
       @b:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users),
       IF(@b > 0, @a/@b, "--invalid--")
FROM Users
LIMIT 0,1
```