# mysql : calculations on alias fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

I already referred :

[How to use alias as field in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081436/how-to-use-alias-as-field-in-mysql)

&

[Adding MySQL alias fields together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373651/adding-mysql-alias-fields-together)

I want to some calculations on alias fields but it throws error

following is my query

```
 select j.*,
    (select sum(stars) from ratingstar where jobid=j.id) as stars,
    (select count(*) from ratingstar where jobid=j.id) as count,
    ((stars/(count*5)*5)) as rating     //I have problem here if I remove this it works fine 
from jobs j inner join proposals p on p.jobid=j.id 
            inner join us_signup u on u.id=p.userid 
            inner join hired h on h.proposalid=p.id 
            where h.status="finished"
```

But it throws error

error in this select line

```
select j.*,
    (select sum(stars) from ratingstar where jobid=j.id) as stars,
    (select count(*) from ratingstar where jobid=j.id) as count,
    ((stars/(count*5)*5)) as rating     //I have problem here if I remove this it works fine
```

and error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unknown
>   column 'stars' in 'field list' query: select j.*,(select sum(stars)
>   from ratingstar where jobid=j.id) as stars,(select count(*) from
>   ratingstar where jobid=j.id) as count,((stars/(count*5)*5)) as rating
>   from jobs j inner join proposals p on p.jobid=j.id inner join
>   us_signup u on u.id=p.userid inner join hired h on h.proposalid=p.id
>   where h.status="finished"' in
>   E:\wamp\www\sugumar\mysuite\includes\classes\MysqliDb.php on line 3637

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Just use [`avg(stars)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg).

Comment: @ Phylogenesis  I tried no luck

Comment: `(select avg(stars) from ratingstar where jobid=j.id) average`

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed a ) at the end

```
((stars/(count*5)*5))
```

edit* you didnt miss it,you just added an useless one at the beginning

```
(stars/(count*5)*5)
```

Comment: You cannot define a column alias and refer to it in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

Count is a reserved SQL term, if you want to use is as a field, you should do it like this:

```
select j.*,
    (select sum(stars) from ratingstar where jobid=j.id) as stars,
    (select count(*) from ratingstar where jobid=j.id) as count,
    ((stars/(`count`*5)*5)) as rating     //I have problem here if I remove this it works fine 
from jobs j inner join proposals p on p.jobid=j.id 
            inner join us_signup u on u.id=p.userid 
            inner join hired h on h.proposalid=p.id 
            where h.status="finished"
```

Comment: You need to quote it everywhere it's used using backtick quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Since count is a reserved word/function, you need to quote it using backticks:

```
select j.*,
    (select sum(`stars`) from `ratingstar` where `jobid` = j.`id`) as `stars`,
    (select count(*) from `ratingstar` where `jobid` = j.`id`) as `count`,
    (`stars` / (`count` * 5) * 5) as `rating`
from `jobs` j 
inner join `proposals` p 
    on p.`jobid` = j.`id` 
inner join `us_signup` u 
    on u.`id` = p.`userid` 
inner join `hired` h 
    on h.`proposalid` = p.`id` 
where h.`status` = "finished"
```

Comment: throws error #1054 - Unknown column 'stars' in 'field list'

Comment: Where does it come from in your query? if it's not in the ratingstar table, what are you counting?