# Retrieve right year in sql

Tags: sql

Goal:
"In which years was the Physics prize awarded but no Chemistry prize. (WARNING - this question is way too hard for this level, you will need to use sub queries or joins). "

Problem:
Don't know how to solve it.

The code can be found in "http://sqlzoo.net/1b.htm", headline 3a.

Comment: Yay! Homework! But, what have you tried so far, again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CTE wrong syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384008/cte-wrong-syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT
   distinct yr
 FROM
   nobel
 WHERE
   yr not in (select yr from nobel where subject in ('Chemistry')) AND
   subject in ('Physics')
```

One option using subqueries.  The subquery gets all the years where there was a chemistry prize which is used to to excude those years with the not in statement.

The distinct yr accounts for the fact that there could have been two prizes awarded.

There's a bunch of different ways to make this work.  Take the code above and try making a join with the subquery work.   That'll give you more practice with subqueries and using them in joins which is a useful thing.

Comment: Copy and paste it into the sqlzoo box.  It'll work :)

Comment: It likely wouldn't have when he made that comment.  The original was filled with typos.  It works now though.

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry. I miscounted the parens and through the physics part was in the subquery. In any case, do you think you ought to be just giving the direct answer to a homework question? I mean, we are gonna have to work with this guy one day...

Comment: If it wasn't a SQLzoo problem, I wouldn't have posted a solution.  Hopefully the OP will take the solution and try some other options with different subqueries or using joins.

Being able to answer relatively straightforward question like this multiple ways is one of the first interview questions asked of candidates where I work.  There's a lot of candidates who struggle with sub's.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Again, the purpose is to improve my abiltiy in SQL!
Beside, it is NOT a homework from school! It has nothing to do with the school.