# sql triple join: ambigious attribute name on a count

Tags: sql, join, count

So I want to count a number of books, but the books are stored in 2 different tables with the same attribute name.
I want to get a result that looks like:

```
  name1 [total number of books of 1]
  name2 [total number of books of 2]
```

I tried this triple join;

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, count(book)
FROM writes w
LEFT JOIN person p on p.id = w.author
LEFT JOIN book b on b.title = w.book
LEFT JOIN controls l on l.controller=p.id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name DESC
```

but since book exists as an attribute in writes and in controls, it cant execute the query.
It can only do it if I leave out one of joins so it can identify book.

How can I tell the sql engine to count the number of both book attributes together for each person?

Comment: name isnt the problem, the count on book is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of database design that you interested in, you should issue 2 different sql and then merge them to handle single output.

A)

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.name as 'Name', count(w.book) as 'Cnt'
FROM writes w
LEFT JOIN person p on p.id = w.author
LEFT JOIN book b on b.title = w.book
```

B)

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.name as 'Name', count(l.book) as 'Cnt'
FROM controls l
LEFT JOIN person p on p.id = l.controller
LEFT JOIN book b on b.title = l.book
```

For your purpose, you can get UNION of A and B.

or you can use them as data source on a third SQL

```
select A.Name, sum(A.Cnt+B.Cnt) 
from  A,  B 
where A.Name = B.Name
group by A.Name
order by A.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH T AS 
( 
  SELECT DISTINCT 'WRITES' FROMTABLE, w.name, w.count(book) 
    FROM writes w
    LEFT JOIN person p on p.id = w.author
    LEFT JOIN book b on b.title = w.book
  GROUP BY name
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DISTINCT 'CONTROLLS' FROMTABLE, c.name, count(c.book) 
    FROM controlls c
    LEFT JOIN person p on p.id = c.author
    LEFT JOIN book b on b.title = c.book
  GROUP BY name
)
SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY NAME
```

Should work.

HTH

Comment: I'm sorry for not checking every question of their OPs for tags... Anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

This will work on a per distinct author's ID to how many books they've written.  The pre-aggregation will return one record per author with how many books by that author.  THEN, join to the person table to get the name.  The reason I am leaving it by ID and Name of the author is... what if you have two authors "John Smith", but they have respective IDs of 123 and 389.  You wouldn't want these rolled-up to the same person (or do you).

```
select
      P.ID,
      P.Name,
      PreAgg.BooksPerAuthor
   from
      ( select
              w.author,
              count(*) BooksPerAuthor
           from
              writes w
           group by
              w.author ) PreAgg
      JOIN Person P
         on PreAgg.Author = P.id
   order by 
      P.Name
```