# SQL query with UNION works, but when i replace with MINUS doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a sequel query for emails of customers without accounts that have only placed orders on over 3 months. If i do the query

```
SELECT checkouts.email 
FROM orders, checkouts 
WHERE orders.id = checkouts.order_id AND orders.user_id is NULL 
AND orders.created_at < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

I get all emails from orders without accounts that were placed within the last 3 months, **BUT** it doesn't account for orders placed within the last 3 months without an account with the same emails from the sql query email list. Therefore, i want to use a MINUS operator to subtract all emails from recent orders. When i try this, i get an error:

```
SELECT checkouts.email 
FROM orders, checkouts 
WHERE orders.id = checkouts.order_id AND orders.user_id is NULL 
AND orders.created_at < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
MINUS 
SELECT checkouts.email 
FROM orders, checkouts 
WHERE orders.id = checkouts.order_id AND orders.user_id is NULL 
AND orders.created_at > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

If i run this same query but with a UNION instead of a MINUS, it works, and essentially gives me all emails from orders without an account, regardless of the date.

**Why does UNION work and not MINUS? How do i fix this query so i can get MINUS to work?**

Comment: MySQL does not support `MINUS` or `EXCEPT`

Comment: Ok. That sucks. Any idea how to do this without using minus?

Comment: Other ways of doing anti semi joins are (1) `OUTER JOIN` and filter on `NULL`, (2) `NOT EXISTS` (3) `NOT IN`. [Some comparisons here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this construct instead (there may be better execution plans with other ways of saying it):

```
SELECT checkouts.email 
FROM orders, checkouts 
WHERE orders.id = checkouts.order_id AND orders.user_id is NULL 
AND orders.created_at < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
AND checkouts.email NOT IN (
    SELECT checkouts.email 
    FROM orders, checkouts 
    WHERE orders.id = checkouts.order_id AND orders.user_id is NULL 
    AND orders.created_at > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
)
```

You may also want to add handling for `checkouts.email IS NULL`, since that WILL NOT be NOT IN (if that phrasing makes any sense), because NULL is never = or <> to anything.

```
SELECT checkouts.email 
FROM orders, checkouts 
WHERE orders.id = checkouts.order_id AND orders.user_id is NULL 
AND orders.created_at < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
AND (
    checkouts.email IS NULL
    OR
    checkouts.email NOT IN (
        SELECT checkouts.email 
        FROM orders, checkouts 
        WHERE orders.id = checkouts.order_id AND orders.user_id is NULL 
        AND orders.created_at > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
    )
)
```

You might also consider more simply:

```
SELECT checkouts.email, MAX(orders.created_at)
FROM orders, checkouts 
WHERE orders.id = checkouts.order_id AND orders.user_id is NULL
GROUP BY checkouts.email 
HAVING MAX(orders.created_at) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

Comment: Your answer looks good, but the query is still running and hasn't finished. I will let you know if this works as expected.

Comment: @Zyren I would try an `OUTER LEFT JOIN` to the subquery instead.  It's possible that the execution plan is actually running that set for each row in the first set instead of joining the two sets.

Comment: @Zyren Unfortunately, MySQL also doesn't support CTEs/subquery factoring, so you cannot use those techniques to make it more performant or readable either: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1382618/18255

Comment: @Zyren I added a much simpler construction which I would think would be pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't do date arithmetic...  you have to use DATE_ADD() or DATE_SUB() such as

```
DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH )
DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH )
```

Also, dates can be a PITA.  If the created_at is inclusive of time, you want to make sure you get the DATE ONLY portion so it implies 12:00:00 AM (which is ok with the CURDATE() function).  However, similar with your ENDING Date...  if your ending date is  Feb 24, 2012 but want to include up to Feb 24, 2012 11:59:59pm, you would be best to do LESS than one DAY more.. ex: < Feb 25, 2012