# Using a variable with pure SQL

Tags: sql

I want to rewrite the following query by assigning a "variable name" to the nested query.

```
select lastname 
  from table2 
 where firstname = (select name from table1 where val="whatever")
```

I want the query to look something like this:

```
( select name 
    from table1 
   where val = "whatever") as retrieved_name;

select lastname 
  from table2 
 where firstname = retrieved_name
```

Is it possible in pure SQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I guess making `SQL` looks like every other programming language which have variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible in pure SQL?

**No.**

You don't have variables with "pure SQL". You can have variables with Oralce-PL\SQL and etc'.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, if you're willing to use a `join` instead of a sub-select and you're [*not* using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql) you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
with retrieved_name as ( 
  select name 
    from table1 
   where val = "whatever" 
         )
select lastname
  from table2 t2
  join retrieved_name t1
    on t2.firstname = t1.name
```

As a_horse_with_no_name pointed out this is identical to:

```
select lastname
  from table2 t2
  join ( select name 
           from table1 
           where val = "whatever" ) t1
    on t2.firstname = t1.name
```

I actually prefer the inline view of the second example rather than a CTE unless the query is ridiculous but it's just a personal preference.

Comment: In this case the CTE can easily be replaced by a derived table ("inline view"). Just replace the `retrieved_name` with the select from the with clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, of course! I'm assuming the actual query is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this instead

`select name as retrieved_name from table1 where val="whatever");`
`select lastname from table2 where firstname=retrieved_name`

Comment: No you can not. (Not just because of the unmatched `)`)