# WITH clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle, common-table-expression

Does MySQL support common table expressions?  For example in Oracle there's the `WITH` clause? :

```
WITH aliasname
AS
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name )
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dept,aliasname
```

Comment: `AS` is used for alias name don't know about oracle. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @BhavikShah - they're asking about support for common table expressions in MySQL

Comment: No - see [How do you use the "WITH" clause in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: MySql 8.0 introduces CTEs: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.name,
       t.num
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN (SELECT c.id,COUNT(*) 'num1'
          FROM TABLE1 c
         WHERE c.column = 'a'
      GROUP BY c.id) ta1 ON ta1.id = t.id
 JOIN (SELECT d.id,COUNT(*) 'num2'
          FROM TABLE2 d
         WHERE d.column = 'a'
      GROUP BY d.id) ta2 ON ta2.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a subquery:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM dept,
  ( 
      SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM table_name
  ) AS aliasname
```

Note that the `,` between the two tables will cross join the two tables the same as in your query you posted. IF there is any relation between them you can `JOIN` them instead.

Comment: Is it WITH clause in mysql ?

Comment: @Madhav No there is no `WITH` in MySQL, as I understand from the question, he needs something like Oracle CTE which is defined using the `WITH` clause, the alternative way in mysql is to use a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

No, MySQL does not support Common Table Expressions (CTE). So instead of using `WITH tablealias as (....)`, you will have to do a subquery.

For example,

```
WITH totalcount AS 
(select userid, count(*) as tot from logins group by userid)
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, b.tot
FROM users a
INNER JOIN 
totalcount b 
    on a.userid = b.userid
```

can be re-written in MySQL as

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, b.totalcount
FROM users a
INNER JOIN 
(select userid, count(*) as tot from logins group by userid) b 
    on a.userid = b.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's talk about `WITH` clause .

`WITH` clause and INNER JOIN otherwise JOIN are a kind of same , but `WITH` clause gives you much more latitude especially in `WHERE` clause ;

I am going to make a view that'll get values like count of users , user name and etc.

First (Creating our tables users and inserted_users) :

inserted_users table :

```
 CREATE TABLE users (id BIGINT(10) AUTO INCEREMENT PRIMARY KEY , name VARCHAR(50))
```

users table :

```
CREATE TABLE users (id BIGINT(10) AUTO INCEREMENT PRIMARY KEY , name VARCHAR(50) , gender TINYINT(1))
```

Second (Inserting some values to work with) :

users table :

```
INSERT INTO users (name,gender) VALUES ('Abolfazl M' , 1)
```

I don't want to insert into inserted_users by query , but I want to add a `TRUGGER` which will insert data automatically to users_inserted table before data be inserted into users table.

Third (Creating trigger add_uinserted) :

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS add_uinserted BEFORE INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

IF NEW.name <> '' THEN 

     INSERT INTO users_inserted (name) VALUES (NEW.name);

ELSE 

INSERT INTO users (name,gender) VALUES ('Unknown',NEW.gender);
INSERT INTO users_inserted (name) VALUES ('Unknown');

END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Run the query and the trigger will be created and at last let's create a view to give us result from a query having WITH clause .

```
CREATE VIEW select_users AS

WITH GetCAll AS (
SELECT u1.id As Uid ,COUNT(u1.name) AS CnAll FROM users u1 
)

SELECT u1.name AS NAME,CASE 
WHEN s1.gender = 1 THEN "MALE"
WHEN s1.gender = 0 THEN "FEMALE"
ELSE "UNKNOWN"
END AS GENDER,CASE 
WHEN u1.id = gca.Uid THEN "INSERTED TO users_inserted"
ELSE "NOT INSERTED TO users_inserted"
END AS INSERTED,gca.CnAll FROM GetCAll AS gca INNER JOIN users u1;
```

After you query got ran the view will be created and by calling the view **select_users** the data will be shown

Last step (calling the select_users view) :

```
SELECT * FROM select_users
```

Thanks for taking a look at my answer , and **that's it !!**