# pl sql query recuresive looping

Tags: postgresql

i have only one table "tbl_test"

Which have table filed given below

```
tbl_test table
trx_id | proj_num  | parent_num|
1      | 14        | 0         |
2      | 14        | 1         |
3      | 14        | 2         |
4      | 14        | 0         |
5      | 14        | 3         |
6      | 15        | 0         |
```

Result i want is : when trx_id value 5 is fetched

it's a parent child relationship. so,

```
trx_id -> parent_num
5      -> 3
3      -> 2
2      -> 1
```

That means output value:

```
3
2
1
```

Getting all parent chain

Query i used :

```
SELECT *  FROM ( 
    WITH RECURSIVE tree_data(project_num, task_num, parent_task_num) AS( 
    SELECT project_num, task_num, parent_task_num 
          FROM tb_task 
          WHERE project_num = 14 and task_num = 5
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT child.project_num, child.task_num, child.parent_task_num
              FROM tree_data parent Join tb_task child 
               ON parent.task_num = child.task_num AND parent.task_num = child.parent_task_num 
             ) 
          SELECT project_num, task_num, parent_task_num 
           FROM tree_data 
              ) AS tree_list ;
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Look at recursive CTEs (`WITH RECURSIVE` queries).

Comment: Checked but confusing...

Comment: Mysql doesn't support WITH, so better try this one,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql

Comment: @face.peck This is tagged as postgresql.  Where do you get mysql from?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do this with pl/pgsql.  You can do it straight in SQL.  Consider:

```
WITH RECURSIVE my_tree AS (
     SELECT trx_id as id, parent_id as parent, trx_id::text as path, 1 as level
       FROM tbl_test
      WHERE trx_id = 5 -- start value
  UNION ALL
     SELECT t.trx_id, t.parent_id, p.path || ',' || t.trx_id::text, p.level + 1
       FROM my_tree p
       JOIN tbl_text t ON t.trx_id = p.parent
)
select * from my_tree;
```

Comment: this query go on running .Not stopping and throwing output

Comment: Is it possible you have a hierarchical loop?  If you want to see what it is returning add to the second SELECT in my_tree, `WHERE level < 5` and it will only return the first 4 iterations.  This can be useful for debugging in this case.

Comment: Also noting, if you are *expecting* loops (i.e. this is a graph instead of a tree), you have to do some extra things to filter them out,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgresSQL, try using a [WITH clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH regional_sales AS (    
        SELECT region, SUM(amount) AS total_sales
         FROM orders
         GROUP BY region
         ), top_regions AS (
         SELECT region
        FROM regional_sales
        WHERE total_sales > (SELECT SUM(total_sales)/10 FROM regional_sales)
        )
SELECT region,
       product,
       SUM(quantity) AS product_units,
       SUM(amount) AS product_sales
FROM orders
WHERE region IN (SELECT region FROM top_regions)
GROUP BY region, product;
```