# specific sql Update query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I wanted to do an "update" to any item that is in the domain [FirstItem +5 or - 5]
example:

i have a table like:

```
462 458 768 466
```

after the update it will be like:

```
462 462 768 462
```

because:

`458` and `466` are included in the domain
`[457.458.459.460.461(462)463.464.465.466.467]`

I hope I was clear

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the table in question

Comment: i'm usine MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your SQL have support for the WITH command,
you might do the following:

```
WITH MyItem(fItem) AS (SELECT first(item) as fItem FROM TableName) 
Update TableName SET Item = fItem
WHERE Item Between fItem-5 AND fItem+5
```

If first command don't exists try

```
WITH MyItem(fItem) AS (SELECT TOP 1 item as fItem FROM TableName) 
Update TableName SET Item = fItem
WHERE Item Between fItem-5 AND fItem+5
```

Comment: Indeed MYSql don't provides WITH resources according this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql