# How to select a specific range from first row with each id MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a table in html to display first rows of each id and allow user to select specific range they want to see, but not sure how I can write it in query.

```
With results as 
 (
   i.*, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.ID ORDER BY I.ID DESC) AS [RN] 
   FROM HolidayList AS I
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ID, MIN(CreateDate) FROM HolidayList GROUP BY ID
   )
   AS j ON i.ID = j.ID AND i.CreateDate = j.CreateDate
 )
 SELECT * FROM results WHERE [RN] = 1;
```

***UPDATED***

I have tried to inject two `ROW_NUMBER()`, but what I received is row 10 and row 25 and they are first rows of some specific id.

```
 With results as 
     (
       i.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.ID ORDER BY I.ID DESC) AS [RN], 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY I.ID) AS [R]
       FROM HolidayList AS I
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT ID, MIN(CreateDate) FROM HolidayList GROUP BY ID
       )
       AS j ON i.ID = j.ID AND i.CreateDate = j.CreateDate
     )
     SELECT * FROM results WHERE [RN] = 1 AND BETWEEN [R]>10 AND [R]<25
```

What I am really looking for is `select a specific range from all the first row for each id`.

***FINAL***

Thank to McGlothlin, finally I solve it. What I need is a nested `CTE`.

```
With First_CTE as 
         (
           i.*, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.ID ORDER BY I.ID DESC) AS [RN]
           FROM HolidayList AS I
           INNER JOIN (
              SELECT ID, MIN(CreateDate) FROM HolidayList GROUP BY ID
           )
           AS j ON i.ID = j.ID AND i.CreateDate = j.CreateDate
         ),
         results AS 
          (
            SELECT k.*,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY k.ID DESC) AS [R] 
            FROM First_CTE AS k WHERE k.[RN] = 1
          )
          SELECT * FROM results WHERE [R]>10 AND [R]<25
```

Comment: You tagged `mysql` but `mysql` doesn't support CTEs.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql

Comment: The `WHERE` clause on your second posted query should be `WHERE [RN] = 1 AND [RN] BETWEEN ([R]>10 AND [R]<25)`.

Comment: @McGlothlin Thanks you, I didn't know `mysql` doesn't support CTEs. Nice reading.

Comment: @bjones the outcome for the second code doesn't match with what I have imaged it would give. I thought it would produce all the first rows and then from the first row I can select row 10 to row 25 from the first rows.

Comment: @Kim.L By I'm glad I was able to help. Please consider accepting the answer if you believe it adequately answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER I.ID AS [R]
```

I think what you meant was:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY I.ID) AS [R]
```

This is assuming you want to give it a row count over every row that is returned in the CTE. The `ROW_NUMBER()` function requires an `ORDER BY` to be specified, and the `OVER` clause would still require parentheses if you were using a function like `SUM` that could be used without an `ORDER BY`.

Edit: Based on your comment, it sounds like what you're looking for is an `OFFSET`. In that case you would remove the second `ROW_NUMBER` and include something like this:

```
ORDER BY ID OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH FIRST 15 ROWS ONLY
```

This returns rows 11 to 25, sorted by `ID`.

Since the `OFFSET` syntax doesn't work in SQL Server 2008, you should do something like this as your end result:

```
With results as 
    (
      i.*, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.ID ORDER BY I.ID DESC) AS [RN] 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY I.ID) AS [R]
      FROM HolidayList AS I
      INNER JOIN (
         SELECT ID, MIN(CreateDate) FROM HolidayList GROUP BY ID
      )
      AS j ON i.ID = j.ID AND i.CreateDate = j.CreateDate
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM results
    WHERE [RN] = 1
        AND [R] BETWEEN 11 AND 25
```

Comment: Thanks McGlothlin, that helped with half the problem. It solved the error message, but differently to I had imaged it would give me. I thought I would get `from all the first rows select row 10 to row 25`, but the above code gave `each row is numbered and select first rows between row 10 and row 25`. English is not my first language, please correct me if I don't make sense.

Comment: I am thinking out loud, but I have a feeling I may need to nest the above code to get all the first rows, then from there select all the rows.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly. More info here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Oops... just noticed the `sql-server-2008` tag (how ironic). `OFFSET` was introduced in 2012. I'll update.