# Join - Table doesn't exist - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Could someone explain to me, why this will work:

```
select t1.id, t1.age 
from mytable t1 
join (select age 
      from mytable 
      group by age) t2 
  on t1.age = t2.age
```

while using t1 in the second part of the join statement like so

```
select t1.id, t1.age 
from mytable t1 
join (select age 
      from t1 
      group by age) t2 
  on t1.age=t2.age
```

gives me an error?

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 17: Table '[...].t1' doesn't exist
```

In my actual problem, `mytable` corresponds to a selection, so I would like to use `t1` in order avoid having to copy-paste the whole `select ... from etc` statement into the second part of the join statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can not reference in a subquery an outer query, because the parser starts evaluating the subqueries, i.e., in your case

```
(select age from t1 group by age)
```

As table t1 does not exist, it will not work.
Since MySQL does not implement yet Commom Table Expressions (CTE) (it will in Mysql version 8.0) if you really are not willing to repeat the code, you must use Derived Tables or Temporary Tables or views. See [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql)

I think the best choice is just to repeat the code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias in the FROM clause.