# How to do WITH AS in INSERT MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, procedure

I am running a Mysql procedure (MySQL 5.7) with following query :

```
DECLARE LAST_MAC BIGINT;

SET LAST_MAC = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(MAC_ADDRESS), 0) FROM MAC_ADDRESS_TABLE) + 1;
      INSERT INTO MAC_ADDRESS_TABLE(MAC_ADDRESS)
      WITH TEMP (N)
      AS (
        VALUES (LAST_MAC)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT N+1 FROM TEMP WHERE N+1 < (LAST_MAC + CREATED)
      ) SELECT N AS MAC_ADDRESS FROM TEMP;
```

After running the query , i am getting following error :

```
right syntax to use near 'TEMP (N)
      AS (
        VALUES (LAST_MAC)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT N'
```

I have verified this query on `DB2` and `PostgreSQL` . It is working fine . I want to know whether `WITH AS` clause is not supporting in `MySQL procedure` query ? How can i achieve this with any alternative methods ?

Comment: try to update TEMP (N) to TEMP N and check it once

Comment: getting same error

Answer (score 1):

MySql does not support **WITH** clause. For more information about this refer the this [How do you use the "WITH" clause in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql)