# "Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)" mysql

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

My query structure is like below.

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT a, b FROM table1) SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

but it comes with below error

```
Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)
```

I have checked my MySQL version with `mysql --version` command and my MySQL version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

It's an issue with the "with" keyword.

Can you please help me with this concern?

Comment: MySQL prior to version 8.0 doesn't support the WITH clause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql

Comment: @scaisEdge It works with V 8.0. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2f7NEPo72tUM7zLHBX2GXQ/0

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: eacxtly  ..  you are using a Distrib 5.7.25,

Comment: If you can  just cange the version ..

Comment: okay got it. Thanks @scaisEdge

Comment: I'm on `mysql  Ver 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))` and get the same error ! I don't understand.

Comment: In fact, PHPMyAdmin doesn't like the statement WITH and returns an error in SQL query window but it executes the query anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySQL version 8+, or MariaDB 10.2+,  if you need common table expressions.