# Is there any difference, performance wise, with these two queries? (Repeating the where clause inside the sub-query) MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that goes something like this.

```
Select *
FROM FaultCode FC
JOIN (
    SELECT INNER_E.* FROM Equipment INNER_E

) E USING(EquipmentID)
LEFT JOIN AssetType AT ON AT.id_asset_type = E.id_asset_type AND AT.id_language = 'en-us'
LEFT JOIN Project P ON E.current_id_project = P.id_project
WHERE E.id_organization = 100057 AND E.equipment_status = 'ACTIVE'
    AND FC.code_status = 'OPEN'
```

As you can see, in the outside query, there is a where clause in the outside main query.
But also, on the inside, we have an Inner Join statement with the line `SELECT INNER_E.* FROM Equipment INNER_E`. This inner join makes us only retrieve the fault codes that are inside the equipment table (correct me if I'm wrong).

I am trying to optimize this query.

My question is, does it make any difference to do this

```
Select *
FROM FaultCode FC
JOIN (
    SELECT INNER_E.* FROM Equipment INNER_E
    WHERE INNER_E.id_organization = 100057 AND INNER_E.equipment_status = 'ACTIVE'

) E USING(EquipmentID)
LEFT JOIN AssetType AT ON AT.id_asset_type = E.id_asset_type AND AT.id_language = 'en-us'
LEFT JOIN Project P ON E.current_id_project = P.id_project
WHERE E.id_organization = 100057 AND E.equipment_status = 'ACTIVE'
    AND FC.code_status = 'OPEN'
```

So repeating the where clause inside the inner sub query, to further limit it before it joins. Or does the optimizer know to do this automatically?

I tried implementing that line in code, and it seemed to only make my query slower strangely enough. Is there any way I can optimize that query above, or since it's pretty simple, is that the best it's going to get without indexes?

I tried running the Explain Select statement, but I have a hard time parsing what it's telling me. Are there any good resources I can look into to learn some tips or techniques to optimize my query?

I don't have any aggregate functions in my Select fields. So is the only real answer Indexes?

Comment: You might want to move your inner query to a WITH clause and see if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Why is the first subquery needed?  Perhaps simply

```
Select  *
    FROM  FaultCode FC
    JOIN  Equipment AS E  USING(EquipmentID)
    LEFT JOIN  AssetType AT  ON AT.id_asset_type = E.id_asset_type
      AND  AT.id_language = 'en-us'
    LEFT JOIN  Project P  ON E.current_id_project = P.id_project
    WHERE  E.id_organization = 100057
      AND  E.equipment_status = 'ACTIVE'
      AND  FC.code_status = 'OPEN';
```

Likely Indexes:

```
FC:  INDEX(code_status, EquipmentID)
E:  INDEX(id_organization, equipment_status, EquipmentID,)
```

Probably unwise to do `SELECT *` -- It will give you all the columns of all 4 tables.  (Without further details, I cannot suggest any "covering" indexes, which seems likely for AT.)

With my version of the query, your question about repeating the `WHERE` vanishes.  With your version, it is likely to help.  I don't think the Optimizer is smart enough to catch on to what you are doing.

Show us the `EXPLAINs`.  We can help some with what the cryptic stuff is saying.  (And what it is not saying.)

"the best it's going to get without indexes" -- Are you saying you have no indexes??!  Not even a `PRIMARY KEY` for each table?  "So is the only real answer Indexes?"  Every time you write a query against a non-tiny table, you should ask "do the table(s) have adequate indexes for this query?"