# MySQL: can I define a query as a variable?

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is a UNION of two Queries:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id
WHERE u.promoter = true
AND o.ticket = 'HOTEL'

UNION ALL

SELECT first_name, last_name, email
FROM users u
WHERE u.id IN (
'232drt-erty3-dff3',
'sswer3-ddf33-675t',
'we2311-23xxw-11vb'
)
```

I would like to know if is it possibile to define the two queries as variables and call them Q1 and Q2
So that my query becomes something like

```
SELECT *
FROM (
Q1 UNION ALL Q2
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure your mysql version, nor how you are using this query, but it sounds like you want a Common Table Expression (CTE) ~ https://stackoverflow.com/q/1382573/1462295

Comment: Stored procedure may receive these queries as text parameters and execute them in solid query using dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement).

Comment: Short answer no - is there a question behind the question?

Comment: You can write queries in string variables, concatenate them or modify in any way and then execute as prepared statement. But why would you want to do that for something like above? Maybe there is a better solution for the real problem, like (as already mentioned) CTE.

Comment: CTE is actually the best solution. Thank you